# How to close file in imported file Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have two files of a project that I am using, let's call them `file.py`, `process.py`. There are values circulating inside of `process.py`, when I want to save a value to the file, (`process` imports `file.py`) I call a function from `file.py`, Let me visualize it.

**file.py**

```
Open file
Define file operation functions
Close file
```

**Note:** Please note that, the reason I need to explicitly open and close file is because I don't do raw file operations, I use `sqlite`.

**process.py**

```
import file
a = data
call file.function(a)
```

The thing is, file is closed after import is done.(because all source code is run, also the `close` code.) So I can't run any file reading/writing functions from `process.py`.

- **I don't also want to open and close file inside every read/write function defined in `file.py`.**
- I can close the file in `process.py`, rather than `file.py`, to close it
  at a correct time, however this feels inappropriate because I feel
  like I have to handle it in `file.py`, because `process.py` itself
  has nothing to do with the file.

What do you suggest I do ?

Comment: It's ambiguous , please be a little more detailed with actual code.

Comment: @harshil9968 I thought I made the problem clear, could you point out which information is required to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a context manager in file.py which open the file at the beginning and close it at the end. Then process.py become:

```
import file
with file.context_manager():
    a = data
    call file.function(a)
```

Or you can put all the functions of file.py in a class. And you open the file in the `__init__` and close it in the `__del__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/atexit.html) module:

**file.py**

```
import atexit

class FileWrapper(object):

    _file = None

    @staticmethod
    def open(filename):
        if FileWrapper._file and not FileWrapper._file.closed:
            FileWrapper.close()
        FileWrapper._file = open(filename)

    @staticmethod
    def close():
        if FileWrapper._file and not FileWrapper._file.closed:
            FileWrapper._file.close()


atexit.register(FileWrapper.close)

FileWrapper.open("file")
```